# Call a C callback from a Send closure

Tags: rust, ffi

In Rust I have a callback defined as `Box<dyn Fn(MyType) + Send>`. I want to be able to convert a C callback provided by FFI into that signature.

To do that, I created a Rust closure that calls the C callback with a context pointer:

```
let rust_closure = move |data: u32| {
    callback(obj, data);  
};
```

The problem is `obj` in this case is a `c_void`. According to the docs (https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ffi/enum.c_void.html) it should have auto-implemented `Send` and `Sync`. However the compiler tells me:

> the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*const c_void`

How can I convince Rust that my `c_void` is indeed `Send`? I've tried wrapping it in a unit struct and impl'ing `Send` for the struct, but that did not change the error.

I've created a minimal example in the playground.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5737c7449b925ab83e35d2404a6bd9f8

Comment: As you may notice, the compiler complains about `*const c_void` being not `Send`, not `c_void`. But [`*const T: !Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#impl-Send) for `T: ?Send`, which is the case of `c_void` (of course).

Comment: Thanks, that explains the error. Am I just trying to do something that isn't possible then?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think you probably need some sort of interface between C stuff and Rust actual logic. Basically, with a `*const T`, nobody ensured that `obj` was safe to send to an other thread. You must "encode" that you asserted that it is, for example by transforming it in a `&T` with `&*obj` (which is unsafe). This will compile, but I'm not sure if it's sound. It actually depends on the guarantees you have on `obj`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers are automatically `!Send` so the solution is to wrap the pointer in a custom type, that hopefully better describes its use and reasons to guarantee that the pointer is safe to use across threads. I'm assuming you made a solution similar to this:

```
struct UserObj(*const c_void);

// SAFETY: Any user data object must be safe to send between threads.
unsafe impl Send for UserObj {}
```

```
let obj = UserObj(obj);
let rust_closure = move |data: u32| {
    callback(obj.0, data);
};

ch.add_callback(Box::new(rust_closure));
```

Which unfortunately, does yield the same error:

```
error[E0277]: `*const c_void` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:33:25
   |
29 |           let rust_closure = move |data: u32| {
   |  ____________________________-
30 | |             callback(obj.0, data);
31 | |         };
   | |_________- within this `[closure@src/lib.rs:29:28: 31:10]`
32 |           
33 |           ch.add_callback(Box::new(rust_closure));
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `*const c_void` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `[closure@src/lib.rs:29:28: 31:10]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*const c_void`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/lib.rs:29:28: 31:10]`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Fn(u32) + Send`
```

*But why?* We're moving a `UserObj` into the closure and we've asserted to the compiler that it is `Send`. Why does it still complain about `*const c_void`?

As of Rust 2021 edition, closures can capture [disjoint fields](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/disjoint-capture-in-closures.html) rather than the whole object, meaning the above closure would capture `obj.0` instead of `obj` itself, causing the error. My suggestion would be to add a method to get the pointer instead of using field access in this case:

```
struct UserObj(*const c_void);

impl UserObj {
    fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const c_void {
        self.0
    }
}

// SAFETY: Any user data object must be safe to send between threads.
unsafe impl Send for UserObj {}
```

```
let obj = UserObj(obj);
let rust_closure = move |data: u32| {
    callback(obj.as_ptr(), data);
};

ch.add_callback(Box::new(rust_closure));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=531d70fb83207ce7bc523de2bacafb7e)

Comment: Adding `_ = obj;` to the closure's entry is also possible. I'd also like to note that pointers don't implement `Send` more as a lint, because accessing their value is unsafe anyway.

Comment: The Rust version was 1.56 IIRC, but it is more edition 2021 than a specific Rust version. I don't know if there is a way to enable that in prior editions.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Ah thanks! No wonder I didn't see it in the release notes, I wasn't thinking about editions.